# using phonegap-plugin-push with GCM to receive device-agnostic notifications not working o ios

Tags: android, ios, cordova, push-notification

i am using [phonegap-plugin-push](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push) to receive notifications.

The very first part, the registration step, works fine on android and ios. I`m saving the registration token on my server and that part is pretty ok.

However, when my server generates an notification, only android version gets notified.

For each device i created a specific api key, [as shown in the docs](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/ios/client).

But what works for android isn't working for ios.

On android, if my app isn't open i get correctly the notification (vibration+notification)

Is there a way to achieve the same behavior on ios using GCM?

Comment: IMHO, you should use apple push notification (APN) service for iOS devices. At least it works for sure

Comment: @Daniel i'll embrace that option in the very last case, since my app works on android and ios in a transparent way, i think my push notifications should be able to do the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end there is no easy solution for that.

As pointed out by @Daniel, the better way to do it is to configure both GCM and APN. a brief discussion can be found [here](https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/issues/115)